# How to list out elements of a multidimensional array in order

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this two dimensional array:

```
$poss = array( array("W","W"), array("L","L"), array("L","W"), array("W","L") );
```

I want each element of array $poss to be listed out in columns each 12 rows deep, an element can be repeated in a column. Something like this(a sample column)

```
W,W
L.L
L.W
W,L
W,W
L.L
L.W
W,L
W,W
L.L
L.W
W,L
```

I wrote the following code but it's not giving the desired result.

```
$poss = array( array("W","W"), array("L","L"), array("L","W"), array("W","L") );

for($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++)   
{
    for($y = 0; $y < 2; $y++)
    {
        echo $poss[$x][$y];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What result is it giving?

Comment: Why sometimes dot, sometimes coma ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
You can use bit logic to generate such table (the base approach taken from this [blog post](https://r.je/php-find-every-combination.html)):

```
$columns = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 4096; $i++) {
    $column = str_replace(
        ['0', '1'],
        ['L', 'W'],
        str_pad(decbin($i), 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)
    );

    echo $column, PHP_EOL;

    $columns[] = str_split($column);
}
```

### Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/686f8005b5f17b2a59e321a9f34a523ac6eb928a).

You can generate all permutations with [`pc_next_permutation`](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_26.htm) and then use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to divide them into columns:

```
function pc_next_permutation($p, $size) {
    // slide down the array looking for where we're smaller than the next guy
    for ($i = $size - 1; $p[$i] >= $p[$i+1]; --$i) { }

    // if this doesn't occur, we've finished our permutations
    // the array is reversed: (1, 2, 3, 4) => (4, 3, 2, 1)
    if ($i == -1) { return false; }

    // slide down the array looking for a bigger number than what we found before
    for ($j = $size; $p[$j] <= $p[$i]; --$j) { }

    // swap them
    $tmp = $p[$i]; $p[$i] = $p[$j]; $p[$j] = $tmp;

    // now reverse the elements in between by swapping the ends
    for (++$i, $j = $size; $i < $j; ++$i, --$j) {
         $tmp = $p[$i]; $p[$i] = $p[$j]; $p[$j] = $tmp;
    }

    return $p;
}

$set = array_map(function ($a) {
    return implode(',', $a);
}, array( array("W","W"), array("L","L"), array("L","W"), array("W","L") ));
$size = count($set) - 1;
$perm = range(0, $size);
$j = 0;

do { 
     foreach ($perm as $i) { $perms[] = $set[$i]; }
} while ($perm = pc_next_permutation($perm, $size) and ++$j);

array_map(function (...$row) {
    echo implode(' | ', $row), PHP_EOL;
}, ...array_chunk($perms, 12));
```

This will give you output:

```
W,W | W,W | L,L | L,L | L,W | L,W | W,L | W,L
L,L | L,W | W,W | L,W | W,W | L,L | W,W | L,L
L,W | W,L | L,W | W,L | L,L | W,L | L,L | L,W
W,L | L,L | W,L | W,W | W,L | W,W | L,W | W,W
W,W | W,W | L,L | L,L | L,W | L,W | W,L | W,L
L,L | W,L | W,W | W,L | W,W | W,L | W,W | L,W
W,L | L,L | W,L | W,W | W,L | W,W | L,W | W,W
L,W | L,W | L,W | L,W | L,L | L,L | L,L | L,L
W,W | W,W | L,L | L,L | L,W | L,W | W,L | W,L
L,W | W,L | L,W | W,L | L,L | W,L | L,L | L,W
L,L | L,W | W,W | L,W | W,W | L,L | W,W | L,L
W,L | L,L | W,L | W,W | W,L | W,W | L,W | W,W
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f3e242ddd5806362f9eb0167ca62348f1900eb0).

Comment: Thanks, this is close but it didn't produce all possible outcomes e.g a column consisting of W,W or L,L only is not on the list.

Comment: I know beforehand that there should be 4096 of such columns. If that can be of use.

Comment: @bodesam, sorry, but I cannot figure out what do you want to achieve. Maybe, you can provide some info about what is your domain, and what these letters mean?

Comment: Ok.Thanks. W for Win, L for Loose. The two possible outcomes of a football match. In this scenario we have 12 matches being played simultaneously, we want to generate all the possible outcomes for the 12 matches.

Comment: Ooops. WW, LL are invalid options.

Comment: Thanks. What does LLLLLLLWWLLW mean for example.  There are 12 matches, 24  teams. L,W means team A Wins Team B Loooses

Comment: @bodesam, there are 12 letters, each represents match result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
$poss = array( array("W","W"), array("L","L"), array("L","W"), array("W","L") );

for ( $x = 0; $x < 3; $x++ ) {
    foreach( $poss as $value ) {
        echo implode("," ,$value ). "<br />";
    }
}
```

This will result to:

```
W,W
L,L
L,W
W,L
W,W
L,L
L,W
W,L
W,W
L,L
L,W
W,L
```

---

**Update:**

12-row columns containing all the various possible combinations of the array elements

```
foreach( $poss as $key1 => $value1 ) {
    foreach( $poss as $key2 => $value2 ) {
        if ( $key1 != $key2 ) echo $value1[0] . "," . $value2[1] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

This will result to:

```
W,L
W,W
W,L
L,W
L,W
L,L
L,W
L,L
L,L
W,W
W,L
W,W
```

Comment: The OP said "12 rows deep", no ?

Comment: Opss.. Yeah.. Updated.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make the code generate several 12-row columns that contains all the various possible combinations of the array elements?

Comment: What do you mean? You might want to give an example.

Comment: @bodesam Instead of 3, you could use `N/count($pos)`. If N is a multiple of `count($pos)`.

Comment: Kinda hard to tell if these are all combinations since there are 2 letters involved.

Comment: Yes. It produces just 1 column, I mean can we make it repeat so that more such vertical columns containing other re-arragements of W,L,  W,W, L,W ...would be produced? It has to do with permutation and combinations

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to achieve. You need to give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep it simple:

```
foreach ($poss as $row) echo implode(',',$row).'<br>';
```

Copied the `implode()` from Eddie because it is a good idea. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $poss = array( array("W","W"), array("L","L"), array("L","W"), array("W","L") );

for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
      foreach ($poss as $item ){
          if(is_array($item)){
             foreach ($item as $value){
               echo $value;
        }
        echo "<br>";
        }
}
    }
```